# How would I go about automatically creating new buttons in discord.py depending on user input?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

What I need is for a user to input a number of arguments into a modal (max of 5), and then those arguments are passed to buttons, with each argument having its own button. I have tried using a for loop, but using the only way I know how to make buttons what happens is I just get a single button.

```
class ButtonView(discord.ui.View):
    for _ in range(int(poptions)):
        print(bnum)

        @discord.ui.button(label=f"{optionsdict[guildid][bnum]}", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
        async def first_button_callback(self, button, interaction):
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"You voted for {optionsdict[guildid][bnum]}", ephemeral=True)

        if bnum != poptions:
            bnum += 1
```

Is there any other method of creating buttons that would allow them to be dynamically created? I figure I could just use 5 if statements but I am wondering if there's any more graceful way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`View.add_item`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=add_item#discord.ui.View.add_item) to add something to a view, and just create [`Button`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=button#discord.ui.Button) instances manually.